# MongoClient multiple connections using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a module for NodeJS to connecto to MongoDB. I've seen that the new, better approach is to use MongoClient, but I can't get to know how can I make concurrent operations on the database. The goal I want to achieve is to have functions to abstract the database, like the following:

```
exports.insertItem(item){

     //Whatever

}
```

According to the docs, I am supposed to connect to the database this way:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, db) {

  //Do stuff on the db object

});
```

The problem is how I am supposed to reuse the db object if it's not in a scope I can use to export functions in node? Am I supposed to make a MongoClient.connect() on every function that deals with the DB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse mongodb connection in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647779/how-to-reuse-mongodb-connection-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You make a single db connection and reuse it everywhere

A typical pattern for modules is

```
export.myinsert = function(db) {
  return function(whatever) {
  }
}
```

and then do

```
require('mymodule')(db)
```

Have a look at an example

https://github.com/christkv/tic-tac-toe-steps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stripped down version of some code that I use to show the overall concept...Hopefully this helps you get started.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var db;

// Initialize our connection to MongoDB once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, database){
    if(err){
        console.log('MongoClient connect failed');
        console.log(err);
    }

    db =  database;
});

exports.Connect = function (callback) {
    callback(db);
};

exports.MongoClient = MongoClient;
exports.ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
```

To use it

```
var Connect = require('myMongo').Connect;
Connect(function(db){
  // then use your db.collection() stuff here
})
```