# MongoDB: Async function doesn't end on complete or how to close connection properly with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> This problem is more relevant to MongoDB and `mongoose` driver, not the async/await code itself.

I have the following code in my `*.js` file:

```js
const model1 = require("../../db/model1");
const model2 = require("../../db/model2");
const {connection} = require('mongoose');

async function f() {
    try {
        let token = await model2.findById(id) //find just one doc 
        let cursor = await model1.find({}).limit(5).cursor()
        for (let c = await cursor.next(); c != null; c = await cursor.next()) {
            //BLAH BLAH BLAH LOGIC
        }  
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }  
}

f().then(r => {
    connection.close();
    console.log('close');
    return r
});
```

So the problem is:

> When I am using just one `model` with `require` (CommonJS) the function ends properly with the following message: `Process finished with exit code 0`, but when I add the second model to the file (*`model2` in my case, but it could be any model file or another function with `require` model*) then function doesn't end.
>
> It doesn't mean that `connection.close()` doesn't work, according to `debug` console of WebStorm it does, message *close* from `console.log()` prints successfully, but for some reason the process doesn't end at all.
>   I have seen on SO other questions about `connection.close` like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813838/properly-close-mongooses-connection-once-youre-done), but none of them have been relevant to my problem. Docs said that one `close()` is enough and it closes all the connections in a pool.

Every model that I import have the following structure, without any exceptions:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

require('dotenv').config();
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.login}:${process.env.password}@${process.env.hostname}/${process.env.auth_db}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    bufferMaxEntries: 0,
    retryWrites: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    w: "majority",
    family: 4
});

let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    },
    any_field: {
        type: String,
    },
},{
    timestamps: true
});

let keys_db = mongoose.model('keys', schema);

module.exports = keys_db;
```

Cause `model` code doesn't have any `setTimeout` or other function except `connect` to DB it shouldn't block the thread. So I can't understand what's going wrong with that and I guess someone on SO have already face the similar problem and could provide some clarification to me. Or it a normal behavior of async function and I shouldn't see a problem in it?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you call `mongoose.connect` in each model file instead of just once in a common file?

Comment: @thammadam yeah there is not, guess it was the problem

Comment: I guess it could be a problem. Try to move `mongoose.connect` to a common file. If it does solve your issue, please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @thammada, yes already does it. Thank you so much for your advice, to be honest I have seen it just now, not 40 mins ago. It could save 30 mins of my time, but at least I capable of solving this problem myself, so it's not so bad, right?

Comment: I guess the best way to learn is to is through experience you have built up by yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found it, using `connect` in every model is a bad practice. Unfortunately, [it's very poorly described in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) manual.

As a result, it's a problem of a bad architecture in my project. So, the correct answer lies below:

> Instead of using `connect` in every schema/model file, you should (use) `connect` just once and then export it
>
> Or make a separate connection for every core/sensitive function for example, separate connection for back-end and front-end but not every connection for every function (like I did)

As I mention before, mongoose docs describe this pattern very poor, and [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-disconnect) for `connection.close()` describe this method, like you could close all-connections-at-once. (Which is actually true, but it won't help you in that case)

I also found this questions on Stack Overflow very useful in my research:

- [Export and reuse my mongoose connection across multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293202/export-and-reuse-my-mongoose-connection-across-multiple-models)
- [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project/19475259#19475259)

Comment: You actually mentioned the documentation of `mongoose.disconnect()`, which internally called `connection.close()` on all connections, might be worth mentioning the difference