# How to reuse mongodb connection through Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I want to reuse MongoDB connection. I 'am aware of [How to reuse mongodb connection in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647779/how-to-reuse-mongodb-connection-in-node-js) 
I want to acheive the same using Promises and Mongo driver v2

Currently I have to connect to db for every request which makes it slow. This is my code

```
"use strict"
var app = require('./utils/express')();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
//Actually I 'am connecting to MongoLab
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/my-mongo';

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('ParkMe app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});


app.get('/location/create', function(req,res,next){
  MongoClient.connect(url).then(function(db) {
    return db.collection('parkme_parkingLots').find({}).toArray().then(function (docs) {
      return docs;
    });
  });
});
```

I want to do something like:

```
"use strict"
var app = require('./utils/express')();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://nidhind:1234@ds051635.mongolab.com:51635/my-mongo';
var db = MongoClient.connect(url).then(function(db) {
    return db;
});

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('ParkMe app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});


app.get('/location/create', function(req,res,next){
  db.collection('parkme_parkingLots').find({}).toArray().then(function (docs) {
    return docs;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there, there are only a couple of changes in your code to be made:

```
"use strict"
var app = require('./utils/express')();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://nidhind:1234@ds051635.mongolab.com:51635/my-mongo';
// no need to call then() yet
var connection = MongoClient.connect(url);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('ParkMe app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});


app.get('/location/create', function(req, res, next) {
  // the connection is opened once, use it at will
  connection.then(function(db) {
    db.collection('parkme_parkingLots').find({}).toArray().then(function(docs) {
      return docs;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Database name ???

Comment: Anyways, I figured it out : )

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it with contemporary syntax.

I put some comments in the code.

> ./db/mongodb.js

```
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 const uri = 'mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/dbName'
 let _db

 const connectDB = async (callback) => {
     try {
         MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, db) => {
             _db = db
             return callback(err)
         })
     } catch (e) {
         throw e
     }
 }

 const getDB = () => _db

 const disconnectDB = () => _db.close()

 module.exports = { connectDB, getDB, disconnectDB }
```

> ./index.js

```
 // Load MongoDB utils
 const MongoDB = require('./db/mongodb')
 // Load queries & mutations
 const Users = require('./users')

 // Improve debugging
 process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
     console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason)
 })

 const seedUser = {
     name: 'Bob Alice',
     email: 'test@dev.null',
     bonusSetting: true
 }

 // Connect to MongoDB and put server instantiation code inside
 // because we start the connection first
 MongoDB.connectDB(async (err) => {
     if (err) throw err
     // Load db & collections
     const db = MongoDB.getDB()
     const users = db.collection('users')

     try {
         // Run some sample operations
         // and pass users collection into models
         const newUser = await Users.createUser(users, seedUser)
         const listUsers = await Users.getUsers(users)
         const findUser = await Users.findUserById(users, newUser._id)

         console.log('CREATE USER')
         console.log(newUser)
         console.log('GET ALL USERS')
         console.log(listUsers)
         console.log('FIND USER')
         console.log(findUser)
     } catch (e) {
         throw e
     }

     const desired = true
     if (desired) {
         // Use disconnectDB for clean driver disconnect
         MongoDB.disconnectDB()
         process.exit(0)
     }
     // Server code anywhere above here inside connectDB()
 })
```

> ./users/index.js

```
 const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

 // Notice how the users collection is passed into the models
 const createUser = async (users, user) => {
     try {
         const results = await users.insertOne(user)
         return results.ops[0]
     } catch (error) {
         throw error
     }
 }

 const getUsers = async (users) => {
     try {
         const results = await users.find().toArray()
         return results
     } catch (error) {
         throw error
     }
 }

 const findUserById = async (users, id) => {
     try {
         if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) throw 'Invalid MongoDB ID.'
         const results = await users.findOne(ObjectID(id))
         return results
     } catch (error) {
         throw error
     }
 }

 // Export garbage as methods on the User object
 module.exports = { createUser, getUsers, findUserById }
```