# Connection Node.js API to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to build an API-REST on Node.js. I did another one before, but now I'm unable to connect to MongoDB database. This database has an auth process, but somehow, credentials aren't working as expected. I can connect locally to the database with them, but not when trying a remote connection.

I read a while about this, and it seems that, due to some updates, the connection string I'm trying to use is not working at all. Here's some code:

config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
port: process.env.PORT || XXXX,
  db: process.env.MONGODB || 'mongodb://user:password@[IP adresss]:[port]/[databaseName]',
  TOKEN_SECRET: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || 'aSecretToken'
}
```

index.js:

```
    'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = require('./app')
const config = require ('./config')

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.db, (err,res) => {
  if(err){
    return console.log(`Error when connecting database: ${err}`)
  }
  console.log('Connection to Mongo database successful...')

  app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`API REST running on [IP Adress]:${config.port}`)
})
})
```

I know that, as always, this might be asked before, and I guess it must be the simplest thing of the world, but I'm really stuck with this s***!

Thanks in advance, guys!

EDIT: Error log

```
(node:3169) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
Error when connecting database: MongoError: Authentication failed.
(node:3169) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Please show your error logs

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about it! It's been already added to the question.

Comment: It's very hard to diagnosis. That error is very common. Are you sure you put correct id, password, host, dbname? Also, check that port is accessible.

Comment: Yes, completely sure. :S

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:password@[IP adresss]:[port]/[databaseName]",{auth:{authdb:"admin"}}, () => {})
```

try put that option.

Comment: It's not working, or I don't know how to make it work =( Any other suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230890/how-to-reuse-mongodb-connection-through-promise