# How to configure MongoDb connection (dbConnection.js file) with MongoDB Node.JS Driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I'm trying to configure the connetion in my dbConnection.js
to connect my MongoDb hosted in Mlab to my NodeJs app hosted in Heroku.

***I believe the problem is permisson.***

**My question**: How can I configure the "connectionString" using **ONLY** the default MongoDb Driver (without Mongoose and similars for exemple plz. I want to make and learn with basic and default method)

**My apllication structure:**
[image]

---

My apllication has a App.Js that calls server.js

```
/* importar as configurações do servidor */
var app = require('./config/server');


var port = (process.env.PORT || 8080);

/* parametrizar a porta de escuta */
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('');
    console.log('|*****************************************************|');
    console.log('|----------- Servidor online na porta: ' + port + ' ----------|');
    console.log('|*****************************************************|');
    console.log('');
})
```

---

My **server.js** uses MongoDb including **dbConnection.js**.

server.js

```
...some code

mongodb  = require('mongodb'), //  <--- var para o banco de dados
objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

//var url = PROD_MONGODB //'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';      
var url = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;

... some code
```

---

My **dbConnection.js** var connMongoDB is:

```
 /* Importar o MongoDB */
var mongo = require('mongodb');


/*var connMongoDB =  function(){
    console.log('========== Entrou na function de connection!  =============');
    var db = new mongo.Db(
            'OPDC',             // PARAM 1 = nome do banco
            new mongo.Server(   // PARAM 2 = objetos basicos de conexao
                'localhost', // string  contendo o endereco  do servidor
                27017,       // porta       
                {}           // opc de config do servidor
            ),
            {}                  //  PARAM 3 = configs opcionais
        );

    return db;
}*/


var connMongoDB =  function(){
    console.log('========== Entrou na function de connection!  =============');
    var db = new mongo.Db(
            'heroku_f6bst99r',       // PARAM 1 = database name
            new mongo.Server(        // PARAM 2 = basic objects for connection
                'ds129776.mlab.com', // string  with the server address
                29776,       // port        
                {}           // server config options?
            ),
            {}                  //  PARAM 3 = opcionals configs 
        );

    return db;
}

module.exports = function(){
    return connMongoDB;
}
```

---

**Some observations:**

- Localhost (app and database) all works
- Published Node still works without database connection (a simple return message for exemple
- I can Connect and use my hosted Mlab MongoDb still

**The error is that below:**
Address: https://opdcapi.herokuapp.com/
Error:

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"not authorized on heroku_f6bst99r to execute command { find: \"brand\", filter: {} }","ok":0,"errmsg":"not authorized on heroku_f6bst99r to execute command { find: \"brand\", filter: {} }","code":13,"codeName":"Unauthorized"}
```

**GITHUB PROJECT: https://github.com/frotaadriano/opdc_nodeAPI**

[image]

Comment: Use `mongoClient` instead, its better

Comment: I already use mongoClient in DAO   
IndexDAO.prototype.getBrands= function(res){
  //res.send({msg:'the API is online!!!!!!!!! '});
  this._connection.open( function(err, mongoclient){
  mongoclient.collection("brand", function(err, collection){
   collection.find().toArray(function(err, result){
 console.log(result);
    if(err){
     //res.status(404).json(err);
     res.json(err);     
    }else{
     //res.status(200).json(result);
     res.json(result);
    } 
    mongoclient.close(); // fechar a conexao
   });
  });
 }); 
}

Comment: Then just `Mongoclient.connect("mongod://<mlab username>:<mlab pass>@<address>.mlab.com:<PORT>/<database name>")` eg `mongodb://<adminuser>:<password>@ds012345-a0.mlab.com:56789/mydb`

Comment: where in my code can I put this??

Answer (score 0):

In dbConnection.js:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongod').MongoClient;
const dbUrl = "mongod://<mlab username>:<mlab pass>@<address>.mlab.com:<PORT>/<database name>";

MongoClient.connect(dbUrl,function(err,db){
           //code
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand all changes I need to Do. I have The dbConnection.js and I pass application to index in route, after Index in Controller and at least IndexDAO. Do I need to replace all dbConnection.js to your suggestion code? And Where Can I execute my CRUDs, inside dbConnection instead my MVC structure?

Comment: Yes you can reaplce your dbconnection but have to export the db object from dbConnection.js to operate CRUD operations in other files. How to export i can answer but there are already many answers present like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647779/how-to-reuse-mongodb-connection-in-node-js